# Find valid occurrences of text from a string

Tags: c#, regex

We are allowing the user to freely type into textbox like this:

```
SomeText[Foo.Id]-[Bar.Value]  (valid)
Xyz[Foo.Id]_[Bar.Value]       (valid)
abc-[pqr]                     (invalid)
```

Predefined values:

```
Foo.Id
Bar.Value
```

What is the best way to ensure that:

1. Texts inside [] should be matching to a predefined set of values
2. If any of the invalid text is entered, identify that wrong text

I think Regex would be the right way to go ahead with this.

Comment: You need to define more clear rules for matching/rejecting your text. Will `[Foo.Id]` and `[Bar.Value]` be valid? And how about this `SomeText[Foo.Id]-[pqr]`. Should it match or not?

Comment: Yes. I have supplied "Predefined values" in the question itself. So Foo.Id & Bar.Value is valid but not [pqr]

Comment: So the general rule is Word + dot + Word?

Comment: @JayNanavaty: So do you want to match the predefined values if they occur with brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flexible way is to extract the text from the `[]` and verify it against a whitelist of your choice:

```
var validWords = new HashSet<string> {"[Foo.Id]", "[Bar.Value]"};

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("SomeText[Foo.Id]-[Bar.Value]-[Big.Mac]", @"(\[.*?\])")) {
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures) {
        if (!validWords.Contains(capture.Value)) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{capture.Value} is not valid (Position {capture.Index})");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a string with all possible values. The string should look like this:

`(?:possible_value1|possible_value2|...|possible_valueN)`

Then use that inside this regex:

```
\w+\[REGEX_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES\][_-]\[REGEX_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES\]
```

For example, considering the only possible values are:

```
Foo.Id
Bar.Value
```

Then the final regex would be:

```
\w+\[(?:Foo.Id|Bar.Value)\][_-]\[(?:Foo.Id|Bar.Value)\]
```

This was considering you allways need two bracket groups.

If only one bracket group is possible, then use:

```
\w+\[REGEX_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES\](?:[_-]\[REGEX_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES\])?
```

If there can exists multiple bracket groups use:

```
\w+\[REGEX_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES\](?:[_-]\[REGEX_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES\])*
```